# Are alert()'s the Javascript equivalent of Visual Studio IDE breakpoints?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ide

I'm trying to find a less haphazard way than a write-and-test way to write Javascript. I don't really use an IDE - I write, then test in browser - if anything's wrong, I then use `alert()`'s to try tracing. This can be a tedious process having to go back and forth from Notepad++ to the browser, so I wonder if there are better ways of doing this, whether there's a good debug-friendly IDE for Javascript / jQuery or something better than alert's to use (dynamic tracing?).

Are alert()'s the Javascript equivalent of Visual Studio IDE breakpoints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of different solutions available.

- Firebug: http://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html
- Venkman Debugger: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_breakpoints_in_venkman
- Aptana: http://docs.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Adding_a_breakpoint

Comment: +1 for actually linking the breakpoint functionality of each tool.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using firefox, check out [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).  its not so much an ide as a slick debugging tool with a lot of extras.

also, if you're looking for something a little more portable, try [blackbird.js](http://www.gscottolson.com/blackbirdjs/)  one of the coolest little debugging tools i've seen, though nowhere near as frilly as firebugs it will work in any browser and provide your log messages and profiles with a visible place on the screen.

Comment: does firebug track all variables, or just the ones you select in advance?

Comment: it keeps track of the values, but will only display the ones you set up a watch for in the watch pane.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and IE8 have built-in developer tools that you can use to debug JavaScript code. Firefox has a plug-in for that, too - called Firebug.